# Electrical wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Loop 3white 1yellow 3bundled black on ceiling. 1 wall switch with2 two toggles. What do I do with yellow. 2 hot white bundled 1white cold left alone. What do I do with yellow. Fan has light and remote.

Comment: This could use some more clarity and more... punctuation?  Also what part of the world are you in?  Wiring varies a lot from place to place.

Comment: I tried to make some sense of it but it needs **much more detail from you**.   Black are Hot, Whites are neutral not "cold", Yellow ??. What does "*One wall switch with 2 two toggles*" mean ?? a photo of the inside of the box would be very helpful. What is the goal here, a new fan  install ?

Comment: Hi Deborah and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll help you but need more information. At this point we know only what you told us and it's not quite enough to respond with an answer. Please post a few pictures, let us some information about the situation and if you have made changes, etc. Please edit your question to add these items

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?